# C++ Filling a class in one rush from a file

Tags: c++

I am currently filling a class like this (which is rather slow for my purposes):

```
void CBinLoader::LoadMatchesFromCompiledDat(clsMatches &uMatches)
{
int size = 0;
fread(&size,sizeof(int),1,m_infile);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    MatchNode newMatch;
    newMatch.EnteredCharacter = ReadWStringFromCompiledDat(m_infile);

    int PossibleResults_size = 0;
    fread(&PossibleResults_size,sizeof(int),1,m_infile);

    for(int j=0; j<PossibleResults_size; j++)
    {
        PossibleResult pr;

        fread(&pr.LenToUseFromEnteredString, sizeof(int), 1, m_infile);

        pr.Trans = ReadWStringFromCompiledDat(m_infile);
        pr.NextChars = ReadWStringFromCompiledDat(m_infile);
        pr.PrevTrans = ReadWStringFromCompiledDat(m_infile);
        pr.PrevPrevTrans = ReadWStringFromCompiledDat(m_infile);

        fread(&pr.SequenceID, sizeof(int), 1, m_infile);

        newMatch.PossibleResults.push_back(pr);
    }                   

    uMatches.Content().push_back(newMatch);

    }
}


wstring CBinLoader::ReadWStringFromCompiledDat(FILE *pFile)
{
    //read the length of the string
    int len = 0;
    fread(&len, sizeof(int), 1, m_infile);

    //make buffer with this length
    wchar_t* pBuffer = NULL;
    pBuffer = new wchar_t[len+1];
    memset(pBuffer, 0, (len+1)*sizeof(wchar_t));

    //read the string into the buffer
    fread(pBuffer, sizeof(wchar_t), len, m_infile);

    wstring result = pBuffer;

    delete pBuffer;
    return result;
}
```

Is it possible to just read it in in one rush instead of filling it up piece by piece?

Comment: How do you determine slowness? Taking a long time is different to being slow.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but you *can* skip the dynamic allocation and simply resize your `std::wstring` to the previously read size, then simply load the string and return it. There is no need for the `new wchar_t[]` nor the subsequent `delete [] pBuffer;` (which you're not doing anyway, instead opting for `delete pBuffer;` so that in itself is a bug).

Comment: If I can read it in one rush, it is quicker than filling it up like in my approach.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ehhhh, I am not sure how that would in code. You mean that I should remove the line "fread(pBuffer, sizeof(wchar_t), len, m_infile);" and remove the line "delete pBuffer"?

Comment: @tmighty I mean you can read the length, resize the `std::wstring` appropriately, then load the string directly, then return it. There is no need for the intermediate dynamic buffer when `std::wstring` can facilitate that for you (which it would anyway when you perform you current assignment; that memory has to come from *somewhere*).

Comment: @WhozCraig There was some reason why I did it that way... I think it was because otherwise Unicode characters were somehow mutilated. Is that possible??? I just wanted to try your approach, but when I tried this... wstring wsNew=fread(wsNew, sizeof(wchar_t), len, m_infile); ... it told me that there is no conversion function from wstring to void *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to write the memory image of a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) to the file and then read it back in (`fread(pMyPod, sizeof(*pMyPod), 1, pFile);`).
However, this is very limited: the memory image is not standardized, so it could even change when switching versions of a compiler and there is a big chance that it changes when switching platforms.
Also, changing the class makes the file useless.

When serializing (to disk), there are many things to consider.  I don't think speed should be a main issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve `ReadWStringFromCompiledDat` method with no memory allocation and memory initialization:

```
wchar_t * pBuffer = NULL;
pBuffer = new wchar_t[len+1];
memset(pBuffer, 0, (len+1)*sizeof(wchar_t));
fread(pBuffer, sizeof(wchar_t), len, m_infile);
```

may be changed by:

```
wchar_t pBuffer[len+1];
fread(pBuffer, sizeof(wchar_t), len, m_infile);
pBuffer[len] = 0;
```

With this new way, you don't overload this method with memory allocations.

Comment: I think `len` is a non-const variable so what you suggested may not compile.

Comment: This uses a VLA, which last I checked is still not supported in C++, at least through C++11.

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, but it requires a completely different way to structure the data and it risk to make your code "platform dependent".

let me give you some more "hint":

- Although we have no idea about how `ReadWString...` are implemented, think about how strings are wrote: if they may have a variable length, there is no way to make it in "one rush", since you have to know when a string ends, before you can read the following one.
- If you can store all your data to be read/written in a statically defined non-polymorphic data structure like

  `struct
  {
     /* only plain types and statically sized arrays here */;
  };`

you can fread / fwrite the entire strut (no matter how big) in one shot but yo uahve to take care about the struct member alignment (that are compiler and platform dependent) if you want your data to be readable by different type of machines.

But before afford "random optimization", try to profile your code after compiling it with all optimization enabled. How much of the "slowness" is due to processing and how much from IO waiting?

If the problem is I/O, you can read the entire file in a row buffer and then process the data from the buffer. If the problem is processing, then you have necessarily to rethink the way data are represented and the what the data structure is stored.