# C++ Most efficient way for serializing/deserializing a vector of int

Tags: c++, vector

I have an application in C++ VS2010.

I have a vector of integers

0=93823

1=987283

2=3183723

3=8892328

4=98382391

etc...

Is there a way to quickly serialize/deserialize this vector to a file in one rush (with the deserialization being cross platform) without having to write each value individually?

Thank you for the help.

Edit:

I am posting some code how I currently serialize and deserialize my vector.
I feel that my way is highly inefficient.

```
void CCompiler::CompileVector(FILE *outfile)
{
    int iSize = nMap.Content().size();
    fwrite(&iSize,sizeof(int),1,outfile);

    for (int i=0;i<nMap.Content().size();i++)
    {
            fwrite( &nMap.Content()[i], sizeof(int), 1, outfile);
    }   
 }

void CBinLoader::LoadVector(clsMapping &uMapping)
{
    int iSizeMap = 0;
    fread(&iSizeMap,sizeof(int),1,m_infile);

    for(int i = 0; i < iSizeMap; i++)
    {
        int iByteStart=0;
        fread(&iByteStart,sizeof(int),1,m_infile);
        uMapping.Add(iByteStart);
    }
 }
```

ps:
In my class clsMapping there are some voids.
However, "Content" simply is a vector .

Comment: What do you mean by "in one rush"? And how would it not (on some level) be writing "each value individually"? At some level, *every* operation on an array will operate on "each value individually".

Comment: @NicolBolas I have added my current code to make my problem more clear.

Comment: *I feel that my way is highly inefficient.* Have you actually profiled it? Is it a bottleneck in your code? Did you compile it with high compiler optimization flags when profiling?

Comment: You could make CBinLoader::LoadVector() a bit more efficient by calling uMapping.reserve(iSizeMap) just before the for loop; that would avoid the vector having to reallocate memory more than once during the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "rush" in this or your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434189/c-filling-a-class-in-one-rush-from-a-file).

However, as it's text, not binary this time, this should work:

```
vector<int> values;

fstream file("filename");

copy(istream_iterator<int>(file),
     istream_iterator<int>(),
     back_inserter(values));
```

Comment: -1: The text in question is of the form `#=#`. The array index followed by the element.

Comment: If I've offended anyone, please let me know the reason for the downvote, and I'll try and improve the answer.

Comment: Downvotes don't mean that someone has been *offended*. It means that your answer is probably wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry, I interpreted the `0=93823` to not be a file format.

Comment: I just wanted to express that the 93823 is the first int value in the vector.

Comment: @PeterWood I write to the file very often, for example using fwrite(&iLenWritten,sizeof(int),1,outfile); Can I just mix my fwrite with fstream?

Comment: @tmighty: "*I just wanted to express that the 93823 is the first int value in the vector.*" OK, so what *exactly* goes into the text file. What does it look like?

Comment: @NicolBolas I simply write the vector into the file. In this file there will be many other vectors and other data.

Comment: @tmighty: Well, how could you possibly tell one "vector" from another? Maybe you should look into some kind of file format. Or maybe look into [a serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). You don't seem to have fully thought through what you're trying to do.

Comment: This code is fine, but I doubt it's any more efficient than what the original poster posted... it's just that now the for loops are hidden inside a library where we can't see them, so it's easier to pretend they don't exit.  ;)